# Dynamic Scalar Variables

Tags: c#, sqlcommand

**Background:**

I have a series of sql queries to run. Depending on the query there may be scalar variables to replace.

**Question:**

Is it possible to add scalar variables to a `SqlCommand` even if that variable is not used in the Query?

**Example:**

Query #1 May use the Scalar Variable `@CashSub` but Query # 2 does not. Can I add `@CashSub` as a parameter without receiving an error?

Code:

```
private void InsertStatements()
{
    foreach (string Query in Client.InsertStatements(CurrentCompany.Modules.ToArray()))
    {
        foreach (Branch CompBranch in CurrentCompany.Branches)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DataDB", CompBranch.AppDB);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("OrigCpnyID", CompBranch.CompanyId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CashAcct", CompBranch.CashAccount);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CashSub", CompBranch.CashSubAccount);

            Queries.RunQuery2(cmd, DestinationConnection.ConnectionString);
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: what happens if you step thru the code / run it..? if you have one that is Scalar why not throw an if() statement where you expect to see that parameter prior to running / executing the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think about adding in front of each addparam something like:

```
   if(Query.Contains("DataDB")) cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DataDB",...)
```

Could also be cleaner storing the parameters in a dictionary with name and value and loop through.

EDIT:

I mean:

```
   var paramRegistry = new Dictionary<string,object>{
      {"@DataDB", CompBranch.AppDB},
      {"@OrigCpnyID", CompBranch. CompanyId},
      {"@CashAcct", CompBranch. CashAccount},
      {"@CashSub", CompBranch. CashSubAccount},
      ...
  };

  foreach (string Query in Client.InsertStatements(CurrentCompany.Modules.ToArray()))
  {
    foreach (Branch CompBranch in CurrentCompany.Branches)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query);

        foreach(var parName in paramRegistry.Keys){
            if (Query.Contains(parName)){
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parName,paramRegistry[parName]);
            }
        }

        Queries.RunQuery2(cmd, DestinationConnection.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Comment: See currently I am just using if(Query.contains)Query.replace....
but I am trying to attempt massive amounts of if statements

Comment: I'm not sure is a good idea to use string.Replace in a sql statement because you have to manually escape parameters values to avoid sql injection and different other issues